# Waffle gives different user names between Tomcat instances

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8, waffle

I'm using Waffle in a Spring application to take advantage of Windows authentication.  When I run the application from Gradle, everything works great.  I get a result such as domain\user.  When I compile down to a war and deploy to a standalone tomcat server, I get the result domain\pc name.

I'm really only using the line

`String username = WindowsAccountImpl.getCurrentUsername();`

Any ideas as to why this is giving different results?

**EDIT:** I had just posted the question with a SO syntax error.  Apologies.  Also, I should mention that both of these Tomcat instances are on the same machine.  (Windows 7, Tomcat 8, Java 8)

Comment: Is Tomcat running as a Windows Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Mark.  It certainly is and as soon as I read your comment I realized it's running as a local user.  No permissions on the domain.  Major palm-to-forehead moment.

Updated to run as user with appropriate permissions on the domain and it fixed everything right up.

Thanks again!